# how to close vb application when shutdown event occurs

Tags: vb.net, process, timer, shutdown, formclosing

I have created an application that starts when windows starts (on startup) but i want to `unload` my form or `close` my vb application securely without losing data

Answer (score 2):

The [FormClosing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing.aspx) event should be the place where you handle expected or unexpected closing of your forms.

This event receives a [FormClosingEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.formclosingeventargs.aspx) that contains the [reason](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.formclosingeventargs.closereason.aspx) for the shutdown of your form.

There is also a more generic [Application.ApplicationExit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.applicationexit.aspx) but it lacks the details given by the FormClosingEventArg parameter passed to the FormClosing event.

How you handle the data that need to be saved could be the discriminant factor in choosing between the two methods.